# Does red wine vinegar and red vinegar taste same?

Tags: wine, vinegar, salad

I am going to cook salad for my lunch, I checked a for recipes. I just eat [halal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halal) food and wine is not halaf, so I am going to use red vinegar (which I don't know even exist) instead of red wine vinegar. Do they taste same?

[This](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/34613/roquefort-pear-salad/?internalSource=hub%20recipe&referringId=96&referringContentType=recipe%20hub&clickId=cardslot%2019) is one of the salads I decided to make; I want to make just vegetable and fruit salad.

Comment: Just for clarity's sake - what sorts of vinegar are *definitely* halal? I thought many of them were alcohol at some point, other than the synthetic options

Comment: Is this red rice vinegar, or something else?

Comment: Red vinegar and red wine vinegar are the same in my country.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek All vinegars are halal, as long as no alcohol inside.

Comment: By the way, that's weird, because there's a vegetarian tag, a kosher tag, and no halal tag???

Comment: @Quidam There is no halal tag.

Comment: I know and it's not normal, since there is a "casher" tag. I'm not Muslim, but it's not fair. If there are Jews, there are also a lot of Muslim people using this site, and the question about halal can be asked here, if the "casher" ones are allowed. No reason for discriminating.

Comment: @Quidam I don't know what does the word "casher" means. But about this community, I should inform you that any users above certain repository score can add or even remove tags.

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to the site @User3176270. I'm not an expert in Halal but my understanding from my halal friends is that red wine vinegar **is** halal because the process of turning the wine into vinegar gets rid of all the alcohol. In fact, all vinegar is derived from alcohol, the sourness is created by bacteria that eats the alcohol and turns it into acetic acid, so all vinegar is halal unless alcohol was added afterwards, which is very rare. You should be fine, although I'm sure you would want to verify that with someone trusted on the subject.

Getting to the actual question, red vinegar is a rice vinegar which is colored and flavored by a fermented red rice. It is a different flavor from red wine vinegar, having less complexity and is also lighter. It may or may not work for you in that recipe, but there's no harm in trying.

Comment: Thank you so much for your good answer :) I am new to cooking and I don't know things very well, that was very helpful. Thanks

Comment: No problem @User3176270, it's why we're here!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot promise the 100% authority of this site, but the wording seems legit to me.  If you do not concede authority to it, I would suggest going directly to a trusted religious source though:

http://www.islamawareness.net/Alcohol/fatwa_vinegar001.html

ETA:  Sorry about the original short answer, the product of illness I am afraid. I normally would have at least tried to summarize what they said, but I am a little hesitant to do so on a subject I only have 2nd hand knowledge of.  This is significant information there, but the jest is similar to my understanding of the rules.  Alcohol is used to produce natural vinegar but the alcohol is consumed in the process.  Insignificant amounts may remain, but that is not the point of the vinegar and it is not enough to produce an alcohol effect.  Additionally, the use of vinegar is not considered an attempt to get around rules, so the use is considered "forgivable" and OK.  Where it would cross lines would indeed be for a fortified vinegar which had alcohol added back in, or maybe the use of just a soured wine which had not been allowed to complete the process.  I think where the debate goes the other way are with things like using wine to cook which those that want to use it say the alcohol cooks out, while those opposed admit that it does not all cook out and question that attempts to retain the wine flavor is circumventing the rules and looks like a violation even if not.

This is not authoritative at all, but when I had my own farm I had customers who wanted Kosher and Halal products.  I did not do it as it would have just involved too many rules for limited return and customers.  But, in general, both groups would have accepted minor violations, provided they were not intentional and major.  An example given by the Halal customer was he could consume a melon that had gotten old and started to ferment.  He could not however add alcohol to it, or intentionally allow it to get old and start to ferment.